# sapui5 - javascript error handling - without try-catch in every callback

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception, try-catch, sapui5

I am developing a SAPUI5-App. Is there a way to show all errors directly to the customer without having to put a try-catch-block into every callback of sapui5? He will use my app in a mobile device and wouldn´t be able to see the log.

I tried already the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
    var extra = !col ? '' : '\ncolumn: ' + col;
    extra += !error ? '' : '\nerror: ' + error;
    alert("Error: " + msg + "\nurl: " + url + "\nline: " + line + extra);
    return false; //true = suppress error alert
};
window.addEventListener("error", handleError, true);

function handleError(evt) {
    if (evt.message) {
        alert("error: "+evt.message +" at linenumber: "+evt.lineno+" of file: "+evt.filename);
    } else {
        alert("error: "+evt.type+" from element: "+(evt.srcElement || evt.target));
    }
}
jQuery.sap.log.addLogListener({
    onLogEntry : function(oLogEntry) {
        if(oLogEntry.level == '1'){
            alert(oLogEntry.details + ' - '+oLogEntry.message);
        }
}});
</script>
```

But I like to actually copy the error-message from the log into an alert for the customer, so he can send me screenshots of the error in his device.

All my attempts did not show enough information or didn´t fire on every error in the console-log.